# Allignment issues in a html form

Tags: html, css

I have the following form in a html5 document.I am a newbie as far as html and css goes.Basically,I am trying to learn with experimenting.

```
<form>
    <ol style="list-style:none">
        <li style="display: inline">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input id="fname" type="text">
        </li>
        <li style="display: inline">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input id="lname" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="dept">Department</label>
            <input id="dept" type="text">
        </li>
   </ol>
</form>
```

Coming to the challenge I am facing,

1)I need to know how I can control the spacing between the label and the input field.

2)Also the space between the two li(first name and last names).

PS:I also have a CSS file which control the font,color,input width etc.

Comment: The `for` attribute of the `label` element references the `id` of the control to which it is related. You don't have ids on your form controls.

Comment: sorry..that was a typo.Edited the code.

Comment: Inputs without names cannot be successful controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `margin-bottom` and `margin-top` on your `input` elements.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) for more info on margins in css.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code.

For "ol li label" (in css code) you can also use **margin** instead of **width**, to control the distance between label and input items.

```
<head>
    <style>
    ol{
        margin:0; 
        padding:0;
    }
    ol li{
        margin:0 0 10px 0; 
    }
    ol li label{
        width:150px; 
        float:left; 
    }
    ol li input{
        float:left;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input name="fname" type="text">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                <input name="lname" type="text">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="dept">Department</label>
                <input id="dept" type="text">
            </li>
       </ol>
    </form>
</body>
```